# Phone stuck on Google logo after trying to install Jelly Bean

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, unbricking

I have a Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.1

I tried to install Jelly Bean, and followed all instructions I found on a website (forgot which one). I installed cwh and twh first.
Then I installed Jelly Bean. After the installation I rebooted my phone and it got stuck on a cross with the four colors for more than one hour.
So I tried to remove all of this (Jelly Bean, twh).
But now it's stuck on Google logo.

I tried everything.
I don't know what to do to make my phone work. I flashed it but it's not working.

Can you help me? (A stressed student who cannot pay for the repairs)

Thank you , I really need an answer

By the way, I have a mac.

Comment: Do you have Nandroid backup of old ROM?

Comment: Do you need your data from the old installation back? Probably not easily possible with your device' current state. If not, you can follow this guide to install CyanogenMod, a well supported aftermarket firmware with nice addon features ([GNexus GSM](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Galaxy_Nexus_(GSM):_Full_Update_Guide) VZW+ Sprint [here](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Google)). It's probably the fastest way to get your phone back into a working state. BTW: It's rather hard to brick the GN completely. Just leave a comment with questions in case you have some!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue long ago with my G1. I forgot to wipe Dalvik cache. It's an option in the recovery menu, you should do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had same experience once where I was stuck at a boot loop after flashing a nightly release of a custom ROM. I tried flashing several other ROM but to no avail.

The reason it happened on my Galaxy Nexus was because I had the option **Automatic Restore** enabled. You can find this option at *Settings -> Backup & Reset -> Automatic Restore*.

My fix was to execute the following command:

```
fastboot -w
```

This command erased the userdata and cache and I managed to boot my device successfully.

In case you don't know what fastboot is, it's a tool that's available from [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Before proceeding with fastboot I suggest you to try flashing some other ROMs.